# How to move insert caret on textbox when accepting a Drop

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview, textbox, drag-and-drop

I have a TreeView and a Multiline Textbox together on the same form in a Windows form.  I have drag and drop setup so that I can drag a node from the TreeView over to the textbox and insert text into the textbox (this is working).

I would like to enhance this so that as the mouse is dragged over the textbox some sort of indicator moves along through the text showing the user where the text will be inserted at, and when dropped it gets inserted at that position.  Currently I just put the text at SelectionStart, but the drag operation does not update SelectionStart so its at whereever the user last had the cursor.

Here's my current code:

```
    private void treeView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            return;

        object item = e.Item;
        treeView1.DoDragDrop(((TreeNode)item).Tag.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Scroll);
    }

    private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Scroll;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
            textBox1.SelectedText = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll want to look at handling the textBox1_DragOver event.  Pass the mouse position contained within the DragOver event args to 'textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition()'

You should be able to use the char position to set the caret's position.

Here is the documentation for [GetCharIndexFromPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getcharindexfromposition(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

What I missed in all these advises about the drag-drop is making the text caret visible. Eventually, I have found that you simply need to set focus into the control! So the final code for the textBox1.DragOver event handler will be as follows. I have included GetCaretIndexFromPoint function from the previous answer:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gives visual feedback where the dragged text will be dropped.
/// </summary>
private void textBox1_DragOver(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    // fake moving the text caret
    textBox1.SelectionStart = GetCaretIndexFromPoint(textBox1, e.X, e.Y);
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    // don't forget to set focus to the text box to make the caret visible!
    textBox1.Focus();
}

/// <remarks>
/// GetCharIndexFromPosition is missing one caret position, as there is one extra caret
/// position than there are characters (an extra one at the end).
/// </remarks>
private int GetCaretIndexFromPoint(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox box, int x, int y)
{
    Point realPoint = box.PointToClient(newPoint(x, y));
    int index = box.GetCharIndexFromPosition(realPoint);
    if (index == box.Text.Length - 1)
    {
        Point caretPoint = box.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);
        if (realPoint.X > caretPoint.X)
        {
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually really irritating as GetCharIndexFromPosition (obviously) is missing one caret position, as there is one extra caret position than there are characters (an extra one at the end). I use this to set SelectionStart on DragOver and Insert on DragDrop.

```
    private int GetCaretIndexFromPoint(TextBox tb, int x, int y)
    {
        Point p = tb.PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
        int i = tb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(p);
        if (i == tb.Text.Length - 1)
        {
            Point c = tb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(i);
            if (p.X > c.X)
                i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Not quite perfect, but it does the job. If anyone finds a native version please let me know :)

Comment: Very irritating indeed.  I may have to try this out.  My workaround was to just append an extra space on start drag, so that you could drop at the end of the text and then remove the space on drop.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a WPF implementation of this solution and couldn't find one. So implemented as follows (Credits to the original solution author). Hope it helps someone who is looking for a WPF version.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Preview DragOver event to set the textbox selection at the precise place where the user dropped the dragged text
    /// </summary>
    private static void element_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs dragEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null && dragEventArgs != null)
        {
            // Set the caret at the position where user ended the drag-drop operation
            Point dropPosition = dragEventArgs.GetPosition(textBox);

            textBox.SelectionStart = GetCaretIndexFromPoint(textBox, dropPosition);
            textBox.SelectionLength = 0;

            // don't forget to set focus to the text box to make the caret visible!
            textBox.Focus();
            dragEventArgs.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the caret index of a given point in the given textbox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox"></param>
    /// <param name="point"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static int GetCaretIndexFromPoint(TextBox textBox, Point point)
    {
        int index = textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(point, true);

        // GetCharacterIndexFromPoint is missing one caret position, as there is one extra caret position than there are characters (an extra one at the end).
        //  We have to add that caret index if the given point is at the end of the textbox
        if (index == textBox.Text.Length - 1)
        {
            // Get the position of the character index using the bounding rectangle
            Rect caretRect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(index);
            Point caretPoint = new Point(caretRect.X, caretRect.Y);

            if (point.X > caretPoint.X)
            {
                index += 1;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for preview drag event in a textbox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="dragEventArgs"></param>
    private static void element_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs dragEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null && dragEventArgs != null && dragEventArgs.Data != null && dragEventArgs.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            string newText = dragEventArgs.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat) as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newText))
            {
                // do your custom logic here
                textBox.Focus();
            }
            dragEventArgs.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To emulate the behavior of common tools (such as Notepad), the GetCaretIndexFromPoint() function must check both the X and Y coordinates.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gives visual feedback where the dragged text will be dropped.
/// </summary>
private void textBox1_DragOver(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    // fake moving the text caret
    textBox1.SelectionStart = GetCaretIndexFromPoint(textBox1, e.X, e.Y);
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    // don't forget to set focus to the text box to make the caret visible!
    textBox1.Focus();
}

/// <remarks>
/// GetCharIndexFromPosition is missing one caret position, as there is one extra caret
/// position than there are characters (an extra one at the end).
/// </remarks>
private int GetCaretIndexFromPoint(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox box, int x, int y)
{
    Point realPoint = box.PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
    int index = box.GetCharIndexFromPosition(realPoint);
    if (index == box.Text.Length - 1)
    {
        Point caretPoint = box.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);
        if ((realPoint.X > caretPoint.X) || (realPoint.Y > caretPoint.y))
        {
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

You can see the difference if the last character in the text box is a new line after a line of text and you drop text below and to the left of the caretPoint versus below and to the right of the caretPoint.

Thank you to user468106 for his excellent answer!